# Laravel Folio - how to manage localized URLs

Tags: laravel, laravel-folio

I am playing arround with Laravel Folio. In my URLs I need the localization as the first part:

"domain.com/de/users" or "domain.com/en/users"

Please check my attachment, how can I solve it without having "users" in both, "de" and "en" folders?

domain.com/users is working great, but I need to have it here:

domain.com/de|en/users

[image]

(I was not able to use the tag "laravel-folio")

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to name the single folder under pages as `[language]`.

The language then is accessible through `{{ $language }}` in the blade files.

Then create a middleware to check the allowed languages and apply it to all routes in Folios Service Provider.